# Facebook OAuth Data Capturing

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I need to capture Oauth data coming from facebook into my table , i have written this code

```
$app_id = "340088232675552";
$canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/appluckyprice/index.php";
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,user_birthday,user_hometown";
```

I am using

```
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$data["user_id"].'';
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

$user_email = $data['user']->email;
echo $user_email;
```

But it isn't displaying anything, How to capture Email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get `email` field by default from Graph API `user` object and need to explicitly request it by passing `fields` arguments.

```
$graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token='.$data["oauth_token"];
```