# Facebook login not showing userdata

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have tried to create a facebook login, but it seems after it redirects it to the my controller, I don't know how to fetch the data. I know I need to call the `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?` part, but I don't know how.

What I did in my view:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/facebook/facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(    'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID',    'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',));      
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
try {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

$params = array( 'scope' => 'email', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com/some/directory/loginusingFacebook', );

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with facebook</a>
```

I don't know how to call `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?` so what I did is after I get in the loginusingFacebook function I try redirecting the url to this:

My Controller after I click the login button:

> redirect(https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="MY_APP_ID"&redirect_uri="http://mywebsite.com/some/directory/anotherfunction"&scope="user_birthday,email");

But I'm having errors with it. How do I pass the user data to loginusingFacebook the first time around with out having to redirect it to the oauth facebook page?

I was hoping that I could get it to go to `loginusingFacebook` or `anotherfunction`  function with the authentication data and userdata so I could echo it out and save it in my database.

Comment: take look of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890818/facebook-oauth-data-capturing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the quotation mark on the redirect_uri.